# Need help understanding a sample PHP while

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

everyone. I saw a PHP `while` loop example today that I don't quite understand.

**Example** ([Complete code](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_xml_parser_expat.asp))

```
// Open XML file
$fp=fopen("note.xml","r");

// Read data
while ($data=fread($fp,4096)) {         // Line about which I have questions
  xml_parse($parser,$data,feof($fp)) or 
  die (sprintf("XML Error: %s at line %d", 
  xml_error_string(xml_get_error_code($parser)),
  xml_get_current_line_number($parser)));
}
```

The expression `$data=fread($fp,4096)` inside the `while` loop parentheses doesn't seem to change at all. It is just ONE assignment statement. How does this loop end? 
The function `xml_parse($parser,$data,feof($fp))` may end when parsing is complete, but I don't see how it will affect the test condition for the `while` loop. I feel the parsing of the XML file would repeat indefinitely.

Also when there is assignment expression as a test condition for a loop, are we really just looking to see if the **RIGHT** side of the assignment yields `TRUE` or `FALSE` to determine whether to end the loop? I have doubt about this though because then it would produce an infinite loop for this example since `$data`, once assigned, will always return `TRUE`.

Thanks

Comment: When fread reaches end of file, it will return null to $data and it becomes false, so that while loop will stop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It ends when the `fread()` function returns false, which does when it reaches the end of the file. You can confirm this in the PHP documentation for fread:

http://php.net/fread

As for your question about the evaluation of the assignment, in PHP when you evaluate an assignment it will return the final value of the variable (different to Javascript for instance, in which the assignment is indeed what becomes evaluated), so you're basically both assigning a value to a variable from a function and evaluating the result of that function (assigned to the variable) without any extra syntax.

Comment: So that means assignment is happening while the file is being read, not after the reading process completes?

Comment: Yes, fread() tries to reads the data from the file, and if it can, returns it, if it couldn't, then returns false, so what ends being assigned to the variable is either the data that was read, or false. Then the `while` statement evaluates the final value of your `$data` variable, and once it can no longer evaluate it as "true" (e.g. if the value is false, null, zero, an empty string, or an empty array), it quits.

Comment: Re-read your original answer and PHP:fread-Manual, I think I understand it now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Work

```
while(there is data to read) OR (!EOF)

break when reach (EOF==true) OR no data to read OR return false
```

`* EOF (end of file)`

Answer (score 0):

As php manual says, the function `fread` **returns the read string or FALSE on failure.**

That means:

`$data=fread($fp,4096)`

In the above statement the value of `$data` is either the contents of your file `note.xml` or `false`. 
As you may know, while loop will continue until the condition is `false`. This statement is `false` only when `fread($fp,4096)` function fails to read data from the file, when there is no data left to read.

Comment: thanks. But I can't make sense of what you said. For example, if $data=fread($fp,4096) is a regular statement outside of while loop. $data would be useless because it would eventually always be FALSE as there will always be a point in time when there is no data left to read?

Comment: Yes, exactly that's why this trick has been used inside while loop to run the while loop until that point reach when the result is `FALSE`